# Are BodyDef / FixtureDef available in Farseer Physics?

Tags: xna, farseer

I've searched through all of the documentation that I can find for Farseer, and cannot find how to use BodyDef / FixtureDef in my projects. Have these been renamed to something else when they were ported over from Box2D?

My main concern is accomplishing something similar to the following:

```
FixtureDef fdef;
fdef.isSensor = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Farseer Physics has origins in Box2D, it is not an exact port of it. It has some similarities but does things it's own way (more familiar with C# programmers I guess). It doesn't use Def classes. I believe the following 2 examples are equivalent:

C++

```
// create a body
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;    
bodyDef.position.Set(-10, 20);
b2Body* body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

// create a shape
b2CircleShape circleShape;
circleShape.m_radius = 0.5f;

// create a fixture
b2FixtureDef myFixtureDef;
myFixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
body->CreateFixture(&myFixtureDef);
```

C#

```
// create a body
var body = world.CreateBody();
body.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
body.Position = new Vector2(-10, 20);

// create a shape
var circleShape = new CircleShape(0.5f);

// create a fixture
var fixture = body.CreateFixture(circleShape);
```

As you can see from the body, the main difference is that you set the properties after creation on the actual instance rather than a def class.

Farseer Physics also makes use of handy Factory classes. Take a look at the documentation for more information.

https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation